# XSL apply-templates priority

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem and I need you.

I had an idea to solve it with the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@foo]" priority="3">
    <p>This text must be systematically added for any rendered element having a foo attribute</p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar1">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element</p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="bar1[@class='1']">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element with class 1</p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="bar1[@class='2']">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element with class 2</p>
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:template match="barN">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the barN element</p>
</xsl:template>
```

When I try to apply this xsl on the following xml:

```
<root>
    <bar1 foo="1"></bar1>
    <bar1 foo="1" class="1"></bar1>
    <bar1 class="2"></bar1>
    <bar1></bar1>
    ...
    <barN foo="n"></barN>
    <barN></barN>
</root>
```

The XSLT engine loops endlessly on the priority="3" template instead of (for my need) applying first the priority="3" template once and then applying the bar1 .. barN templates.

How can I perform this without modifying each of the bar1 .. barN templates (N~=150) to add the systematic text on each element having a foo attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` will always pick the most specific template, which may indeed lead to an infinite recursion.  If you are using XSLT 2.0 then you can use

```
<xsl:next-match/>
```

instead, which picks the next-highest-priority template after the one that is currently executing.  In XSLT 1.0 the only option is to move the generic templates into a different `.xsl` file, have your main one import that, and then use `<xsl:apply-imports/>` to apply templates with a "lower import precedence" (i.e. only consider the templates in the import*ed* file, not the import*ing* one).

**classes.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="bar1">
        <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element</p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bar1[@class='1']">
        <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element with class 1</p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="bar1[@class='2']">
        <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element with class 2</p>
    </xsl:template>
    ...
    <xsl:template match="barN">
        <p>This is the normal rendering for the barN element</p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**main.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="classes.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@foo]" priority="3">
        <p>This text must be systematically added for any rendered element having a foo attribute</p>
        <xsl:apply-imports/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Neat solution using template precedence and `apply-imports`.

Comment: Yess! Thanks, it's precisely what I need. I use the `<xsl:next-match/>` solution but I keep in memory the solution with `<xsl:apply-imports/>` in case of XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You could work with template modes.

```
<xsl:template match="*[@foo]">
    <p>This text must be systematically added for any rendered element having a foo attribute</p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="normal" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar1" mode="normal">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the bar1 element</p>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ... -->

<xsl:template match="barN" mode="normal">
    <p>This is the normal rendering for the barN element</p>
</xsl:template>
```

The point is, when `<xsl:template match="*[@foo]">` matches something and you call a simple `<xsl:apply-templates select="." />` inside it, the same template will of course match again.

Comment: I have already think to use it but I already use them for other contraints. But thanks.

Comment: You should have said so in the question.

Comment: Sorry but the context is very particular and I just forgot to list all constraints